# HttpSessionBindingListner methods not being called

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying a HttpSessionBindingListener example and the events are not firing. What am i doing wrong here.

Here is the code for the Attribute class that i am trying to set and the code for the servlet class.

The servlet is working but is not displaying the output that i am expecting.

```
    public class SimpleAttribute implements HttpSessionBindingListener {

        PrintWriter writer;

        public  SimpleAttribute(PrintWriter writer) {
            this.writer = writer;
        }

        public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
            writer.write("Value bound called");
            writer.write("<br/>");
        }

        public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
            writer.write("value Unbound called");
            writer.write("<br/>");


}
}




public class SessionBindingServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final String SIMPLEATTR = "simpleattribute";

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {

        ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();            
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        try {
            servletContext.removeAttribute(SIMPLEATTR);
            out.write("removed previous attribute successfully");
            out.write("<br/>");
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        servletContext.setAttribute(SIMPLEATTR, new SimpleAttribute(out));
        out.write("Added simple attribute successfully");
        out.write("<br/>");
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting and what are you seeing?

Comment: use HttpSessionAttributeListener instead of HttpSessionBindingListener

Comment: Have you registered the listener in `web.xml`?

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh It's not that kind of listener. The implementing object is the actual object you put in the `HttpSession`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't actually bound the object to an `HttpSession`, you've bound it to the `ServletContext`.

You should be retrieving the `HttpSession` with

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
```

and adding the attribute

```
session.setAttribute(SIMPLEATTR, new SimpleAttribute(out));
```

That will fire an `HttpSessionBindingEvent` which will notify your `HttpSessionBindingListener` implementing class object.

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues in your code:

- A `HttpSessionBindingListener` is notified if the object which implements the interface is bound/unbound to session, not other objects. If you need to be informed by attributes set/get on session, you shall implement `HttpSessionAttributeListener`.
- Have you registered your listener in `web.xml`?
- And finally `HttpSessionAttributeListener` is get notified on session attribute changes not servlet-context attribute changes, if you want that you shall implement `ServletContextAttributeListener`.